# Attach a user's identity to a SQL Server Connection

Tags: c#, sql-server

We have an application that uses a SQL Server login (not AD) to authenticate to the database.  This is a single, generic account, so if we have 100 users logged on, all of the connections that they create have the same user name associated with them.

This poses a challenge for some of the auditing tools that we want to use to monitor inappropriate or errant behavior on the server (they cannot resolve the user).

Is there a better way to manage this connection?
Here are our goals:

We want to authorize the application to access SQL server, not the user (so we don't want the user to be able to fire up Access, or Crystal Reports and start messing with the db, access should be through our code).  For this reason, we have avoided using Integrated Security.

We want to be able to correlate an active process on SQL Server back to the user who started it

We need to be able to work with ORM's (strongly prefer parameterized SQL over stored procs, so we can't just specify execute only permission for AD accounts)

The only options that leaves me with that I know of are:

- Attach some sort of user-specific metadata to the connection
- Use a SQL Server login per user
- Forego any user identity information on our connections

Is there a 4th option that I don't know about?

Comment: Put the user name into the `Application` part of the connection string. But you will lose the benefits of connection pooling and you have to trust the application (as you will with any other method, such as context_info also)

Comment: Alternatively, get the IP address from the SQL Server connection and use that to identify the source/user (which may or may not be practical depending on your situation)

Answer (score 1):

The general approach is to attach a username to all records written... Either via a FK audit/history table or as a column on the table. Your application is what talks to the database - your users don't have any "pass through" that I'm aware of.

Another option is to grab the user's username when they use your application, and place a connectionString in the user's session/whatever that uses integrated credentials with the user's username passed in... Then have the user use their uniquely stored connectionString during their use of the application. That should work, but you'll have to handle the SQLExceptions for permissions etc. in the code... which I suppose you had to handle regardless.